# Pyspark: Getting value from the sum function

Tags: python, pyspark

This looks like simple question but I am struck here for a long time. Could someone help me out.

Input is a table and I wanted to find a sum of values in field total_records. This is what I have done in my program:

meta['xxxx_processed'] = metadata_df.where("filename like '%_xxxx_20160601.txt.gz' ").\
        select('total_records').groupBy().sum()

I am getting as DataFrame[sum(totalrecords): bigint].

Could someone help to get the value rather than the type.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to use `.collect()` to get the actual value?

Comment: I get like this: [Row(sum(totalrecords)=204473674)].

Comment: Can I get value alone

Comment: It seems you're getting a list, so try: `.collect().get(0)`, and show me what you're getting.

Comment: Hi Avihoo, the __getitem__(0) does not seem to work. It still prints as Row(sum(totalrecords)=204473674) and [Row(sum(totalrecords)=None)]. I guess need to take as map.....after processing the records I am displaying the summary of processed records, for which I am calculating the sum.